# Senders mail address of a mail item using Outlook object model

Tags: c#, outlook

1. How to check the senders mail address of an individual or group of a mail item?
2. Is it possible if outlook addin can validate even if outlook is not opened?

This is what I have tried so far but unable to get the SMTP mail address...

```
Outlook.NameSpace mnmspc;
Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox;  
Outlook.Items mitems;  

mnmspc = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");  
inBox = mnmspc.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);  
mitems = inBox.Items;  
foreach (Outlook.MailItem i in mitems) { .... }
```

Thanks in advance.

Amit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SenderName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171985%28v=office.11%29.aspx), [SenderEmailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171942%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [SenderEmailType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171944%28v=office.11%29.aspx) (e.g. exchange or SMTP) properties on MailItem to get information about the sender. Unfortunately, invoking the Outlook API does open Outlook.